# split array element with special character

Tags: bash, python, check-mk

I would like to write a bash script (that would be better if the script is in python) which executes a `Perl` script ( https://github.com/MangeshBiradar/Check_mk/blob/master/check_jenkins_jobs.pl) within it. It is the output that `Perl` script outputs:

```
CRITICAL ~ First_run ~ Build stability: 3 out of the last 4 builds failed. ~ 25
CRITICAL ~ Mangesh_Testing ~ Build stability: All recent builds failed. ~ 0
CRITICAL ~ MKS_Integrity ~ Build stability: All recent builds failed. ~ 0
OK ~ MKS_TEST ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
CRITICAL ~ Rest_api_testing ~  ~ no score
CRITICAL ~ Second_job ~  ~ no score
OK ~ Team_test ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
OK ~ test ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
CRITICAL ~ TEST_1 ~ Build stability: 2 out of the last 3 builds failed. ~ 33
OK ~ Update_Outlook ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
```

Now I have a task to be added into that `bash/python` script is to parse the `Perl` script output. According to the first field(CRITICAL, OK) in the parsed output I would like to return an appropriate value for CRITICAL return 2, for OK return 0 etc.
What are some ways I can achieve this?

Comment: What is the output of the Perl program?

Comment: Here is the output, when I double quoted the script to be executed in back ticks.
its the output I was expecting.

`CRITICAL
 First_run
 Build stability: 3 out of the last 4 builds failed.
 25
CRITICAL
 Mangesh_Testing
 Build stability: All recent builds failed.
 0
CRITICAL
 MKS_Integrity
 Build stability: All recent builds failed.
 0
OK
 MKS_TEST
 Build stability: No recent builds failed.
 100`

Comment: Add that information to the question so you'll be able to format it properly.

Comment: Updated the question with expected output.

Comment: Is that the output of the Perl script that you now want to reformat? Or is that what you want to see and you have not shown what Perl outputs? I don't see any `~` characters there.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. I have updated(I mean changed the question..I apologies for that) Hope this will make sense for You. and Hope I will get proper guidance on Thanks once again!!

Comment: Are you looking for a "return code" for each line?

Comment: Actually I want to split each output line by ~ character and store them into an array, so that I can use that array elements for further use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your for loop a bit:

```
for line in "${array[@]}"
do
   OIFS=$IFS                   # store old IFS in buffer
   IFS='~'                     # set IFS to '-'
   for i in $line
   do
      echo  $i
   done
  IFS=$OIFS
done
```

Comment: Hi Guru..
Updated the question.
I am facing the same issue while I storing the Perl script output into an array and using that array for further work.

Comment: Solved..!! Double quoted the Perl script to be executed in the back ticks.